# When reading from a file in C++, can I just copy the text itself?

Tags: c++, string, file

Sorry, the wording for the actual question is probably wrong. I have a program that reads in a line from a .txt file and then puts the string into an object to compare it to a string entered by the user. I haven't been able to get it to match, and when I've tried to see what is entered, I don't see much. Maybe there's an invisible character denoting the end of the line? I've tried code like this:

```
std::cout << "...." << table[row][col]->get() << "...." <<std::endl;
```

And got

```
....a
```

as the result. When reading the file I used std::getline() if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a true fix, although I did see that the length of the read-in string was one int longer than the actual word. I was able to use a substring to cut the end off of the string.

Comment: You didn't show your txt file, or how you are reading it in. My guess is your txt file uses CRLF line breaks, but you are reading the file in a way that only recognizes LF line breaks, leaving CR in each string.